# MySQL server has gone away

Tags: mysql

Изменил движок на InnoDB и стала периодически вылетать ошибка.
Таймаут увеличил , но ничего не помогает.
Ошибка вылетает в одно и тоже время , но не могу понять, какой скрипт и запрос виноват + не ясно, что нужно исправить

Comment: не ясно что нужно советовать(

Comment: какое-нибудь периодическое задание, выполняющееся где-нибудь в вашей сети.